# How many UUID can an app register using startMonitoringForRegion?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon

Currently my receiver app is able to work with one UUID, this is my code:

```
- (void)startMonitoringItem {
    CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion = [self beaconRegionWithItem];
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:beaconRegion];
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:beaconRegion];
}

- (CLBeaconRegion *)beaconRegionWithItem{

    NSUUID *iPadTransmitterUUID = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"A77A1B68-49A7-4DBF-914C-760D07FBB87B"];

    CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:iPadTransmitterUUID
                                                                       major:1
                                                                       minor:1
                                                                  identifier:@"iPadTransmitter"];
    return beaconRegion;
}
```

I can increment the number of UUID registered for the app. However, there's a limit. From the apple docs:

> An app can register up to 20 regions at a time

Which makes me doubt the feasibility of my app... I want to setup a iBeacon receiver app for a shopping mall of about 500 shops. I want to register for ~500 UUID, but the app will only detect about 5 shops' iBecon UUID at a time. How can I do it when the maximum region is only 20?

What's the maximum number of combination minor and major value?

Comment: The title of this question is incomplete.

Comment: In this scenario you would typically use the same UUID on all beacons, differentiating the via the major and minor.  You can then register a single region to cover all of the shops.  The tricky bit is once you have entered a region you won't get another notification until you exit it, which may be a problem with overlapping regions - so once you get a region entry notification you need to stop monitoring the generic region and start monitoring a region with the specific major/minor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to dealing with a large number of beacons is to create a region with wildcards for the major and minor, so any combination will be matched.  This way you can use as single region to monitor for all your beacons under the same UUID:

```
CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:commonUUID identifier:@"commonRegion"];
```

The above assumes you can make all stores have the same UUID for their beacons.  If you cannot, you can add more UUID-based regions, but you are limited to 20 total regions by iOS.

You will also need to range for beacons if you use this technique, so you can read the actual major and minor identifiers on each beacon.  Your code shows you are doing this anyway.  The logic for taking action on a specific beacon would go inside the ranging callback.

Comment: Thx @davidgyoung. If I'm using only one UUID, is there a limit for ranging? I mean how many major and minor combination can I range? What's the maximum value for major and minor respectively?

Comment: Have posted a new question here, please help :D : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29505807/whats-the-maximum-value-for-major-and-minor-for-ibeacon-transmitter

Comment: Btw what's the reason for them to limit the region to 20? Is it because of the device power usage limitation or something else?

Comment: It is partly a carryover from geofences which use the same base APIs and are also limited to 20 per app due to resource limitations.  For beacon monitoring, the regions are used to make a hardware pattern filter for the Bluetooth chip, which has similar resource limits.