# What's the maximum value for major and minor for iBeacon transmitter?

Tags: objective-c, ibeacon

Question:

1) What's the maximum value for major and minor for iBeacon transmitter?

2) I'm using only one UUID, is there a limit for startRangingBeaconsInRegion to detect the major and minor value?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both Major and Minor is 16bits. So the maximum major/minor is 65535.

Comment: Thx @user4761991, got it! Setting any value more than 65535 eg. (65536) for either major or minor value will be detected as 0 in the didRangeBeacons delegate method. Btw wahts the maximum number of combination for major and minor, my maths s*cks... Is it 4294836225?